# Ksplice: Skipping acquire of configured file

Tags: apt, 32-bit, architecture

I installed [Ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/try/desktop) for Ubuntu 17.10 to enable kernel live patches but now I am getting the following message when running `apt update`.

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'ksplice/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://www.ksplice.com/apt artful InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I assumed a misconfiguration of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ksplice.list` but it looks fine to me:

```
deb http://www.ksplice.com/apt artful ksplice
deb-src http://www.ksplice.com/apt artful ksplice
```

Comment: As it says, the repo doesn't support i386. Limiting to amd64 should remove the notice. (assuming you're on amd64)

Comment: Added `[ arch=amd64 ]` to sources. Thank you!